# How to iterate through an array and have it return only the contacts missing a certain object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I've been working on this for over an hour and have no clue what to include...
directions:

-Filtering Data.. The application's search feature allows users to filter contacts in various ways. The interviewer would like you to filter out those who do not have an Instagram account.

Using the given contacts array, save the contacts who do not have an Instagram account to a variable called 'noInstagram.' Don't just hard-code the answer into the variable but rather filter the contacts out of the array programmatically.

```js
let contacts = [
    {
        name: "Jane Doe",
        age: 21,
        social_media: {
            instagram: "jane.doe",
            twitter: "jane_doe"
        }
    },
    {
        name: "John Doe",
        age: 21,
        social_media: {
            instagram: "john.doe",
            twitter: "john_doe"
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Mary Deer",
        age: 21,
        social_media: {
            twitter: "mary_deer"
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Gary Deer",
        age: 21,
        social_media: {
            twitter: "gary_deer"
        }
    }
]

How Im starting off.  

let noInstagram = contacts.filter((contact) => {
if ( contact.social_media. ????){
console.log(contact)
}
})
```

Comment: `let noInstagram = contacts.filter((contact) => !contact.social_media.instagram);` try this

Comment: @JayVaghasiya thank you so so much! I wasn't even sure how to filter in missing objects. I really appreciate it.. I'm a beginner at this.. but I wont forget the power of "!" every again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let noInstagram = contacts.filter(c => !c.social_media.instagram);
console.log(noInstagram);
```

The `filter` method take a callback function as parameter and return an `array`.

This array is filled with all the element of the inital `array` that return `true` after passing throw the callback function.

Answer (score -1):

```
let noInstagram = contacts.filter(contact => contact.social_media.instagram === undefined);
```

or

```
let noInstagram = contacts.filter(contact => !contact.social_media.hasOwnProperty("instagram"));
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Answer (score -1):

You are going in a good direcction with a filter, please visit [Array.filter docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
let noInstagram = contacts.filter((contact) => {
    //Return true if instagram is not found
    return !contact.social_media.instagram
})
```

As you see, you must return true or false inside the filter to be able to filter or not the current object.